# Two axis plots w.r.t time in pyqtgraph

Tags: plot, pyqtgraph

Can some one help me on how do I create a two axis plots w.r.t time using pyqtgraph. For example plot velocity versus torque against time i.e. time is x axis and is moving and velocity is plotted against torque as a function of time.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.ptime import time
from numpy import *
from socket import *
import time

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
y = [0,2,4,6,8,10,12,16,18,20];

pg.mkQApp()
pw = pg.PlotWidget()
pw.show()

for i in range(1,20):
    p1 = pw.plotItem
    p2 = pg.ViewBox()
    p1.showAxis('right')
    p1.scene().addItem(p2)
    p2.setGeometry(p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())
    p1.getAxis('right').linkToView(p2)
    p2.setXLink(p1)
    x.append(i)
    y.append(i*2)
    p1.plot(x)
    #time.sleep(1)    
    p2.addItem(p1.plot(y, pen='b'))
    #time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a 3D line plot, is that correct? Could you post an example image of the type of plot you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Yep, you are correct. I am looking for a 3D line plot. I tried to attach the sample plot using the edit option above but with error. So I have included the code snippet above. Three solutions that I need are 1.The Z axis is time and is moving i.e. old historic data should be out and new data is only displayed (time frame of Z axis is fixed) 2.Looks like the plot is re drawn every instance i.e. I am seeing multiple graphs within the same frame 3.Also the graph is not being updated dynamically i.e. the graph frame hangs and is displayed only at the end.

Comment: You have provided a 2D plot with two y-axes (which is fine, but not the same as a 3D plot; see examples/GLLinePlotItem.py for a 3D example). 1,2. All data plotted is persistent; call plot.clear() to remove old entries. 3. Qt requires you to either call QtGui.QApplication.processEvents() for each update you want, or start the event loop (QApplication.exec_()) and update the plot from a timer callback.

Comment: Thanks Luke. Now we got what we wanted. We also explored moving the X axis dynamically to show only fresh data in the fixed x axis frame and we got the solution in function setXRange. Now the plot is working as intended. I appreciate the discussion in this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in this forum for this question, the below code snippet is what we were looking for and now is satifying our requirement. This is just a sample code which will be eventually modified and integrated to the intended application. Once again I appreciate the discussion in this forum which helped us in arriving at the right solution.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.ptime import time
from numpy import *
from socket import *
import time

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

plot_x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
plot_y = [0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18];

loopcount = 0;

pg.mkQApp()
pw = pg.PlotWidget()
pw.show()
p1 = pw.plotItem
p2 = pg.ViewBox()
p1.showAxis('right')
p1.scene().addItem(p2)
p2.setGeometry(p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())
p1.getAxis('right').linkToView(p2)
p2.setXLink(p1)

def update():
    global pw, pg, loopcount, plot_x, plot_y, p1, p2

    p1.setXRange(loopcount*10, loopcount*10+100)
    p2.setXRange(loopcount*10, loopcount*10+100)

    p1.plot(plot_x)
    p2.addItem(p1.plot(plot_y, pen='b'))

    loopcount = loopcount + 1

    for update in range(loopcount*10, loopcount*10+100):
        plot_x.append(update*loopcount)
        plot_y.append(update*loopcount*2)

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(50)
```

Improved code based on Luke's comment

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.ptime import time
from numpy import *
from socket import *
import time

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

plot_param1 = [0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18];
plot_param2 = [0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27];

samplesize = 10;
samples     = range(0,samplesize)
framecount = 0;

pg.mkQApp()
pw = pg.PlotWidget()
pw.show()
p1 = pw.plotItem
p2 = pg.ViewBox()
p1.showAxis('right')
p1.scene().addItem(p2)
p2.setGeometry(p1.vb.sceneBoundingRect())
p1.getAxis('right').linkToView(p2)
p2.setXLink(p1)

def update():
    global pw, pg, framecount, plot_param1, plot_param2, p1, p2, samples, samplesize

    p1.plot(samples, plot_param1)
    p2.addItem(p1.plot(samples, plot_param2, pen='b'))

    pw.autoRange()

    p1.setXRange(framecount*samplesize, framecount*samplesize+samplesize)
    p2.setXRange(framecount*samplesize, framecount*samplesize+samplesize)

    if framecount == 0:
        flushloop = samplesize
    else:
        flushloop = samplesize+1

    for flush in range(1,flushloop):
        plot_param1.pop(0)
        plot_param2.pop(0)
        samples.pop(0)

    # below code is to prepare for next sample
    framecount = framecount + 1

    for update in range(framecount*samplesize, framecount*samplesize+samplesize):
        plot_param1.append(update*framecount*2)
        plot_param2.append(update*framecount*3)
        samples.append(update)

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(50)
```

Comment: I see two problems with this: 1) data is not being cleared, and so the performance drops off very quickly as the plots accumulate data.  2) The X-range is increasing more slowly than the data itself, so you are never looking at the newest data.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have provided the improved script based on your feedback in "Improved code based on Luke's comment" in the answer segment above. The old data is flushed from the plot data stores while is retained in the plot history. The X axis is catching up with the data. Kindly have a look at the updated script and give your feedback for any scope for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
pg.setConfigOption('background', '#c7c7c7')
pg.setConfigOption('foreground', '#000000')
from pyqtgraph.ptime import time
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

p = pg.plot()
p.setXRange(0,10)
p.setYRange(-10,10)
p.setWindowTitle('Current-Voltage')
p.setLabel('bottom', 'Bias', units='V', **{'font-size':'20pt'})
p.getAxis('bottom').setPen(pg.mkPen(color='#000000', width=3))
p.setLabel('left', 'Current', units='A',
            color='#c4380d', **{'font-size':'20pt'})
p.getAxis('left').setPen(pg.mkPen(color='#c4380d', width=3))
curve = p.plot(x=[], y=[], pen=pg.mkPen(color='#c4380d'))
p.showAxis('right')
p.setLabel('right', 'Dynamic Resistance', units="<font>&Omega;</font>",
            color='#025b94', **{'font-size':'20pt'})
p.getAxis('right').setPen(pg.mkPen(color='#025b94', width=3))

p2 = pg.ViewBox()
p.scene().addItem(p2)
p.getAxis('right').linkToView(p2)
p2.setXLink(p)
p2.setYRange(-10,10)

curve2 = pg.PlotCurveItem(pen=pg.mkPen(color='#025b94', width=1))
p2.addItem(curve2)

def updateViews():
    global p2
    p2.setGeometry(p.getViewBox().sceneBoundingRect())
    p2.linkedViewChanged(p.getViewBox(), p2.XAxis)

updateViews()
p.getViewBox().sigResized.connect(updateViews)

x = np.arange(0, 10.01,0.01)
data = 5+np.sin(30*x)
data2 = -5+np.cos(30*x)
ptr = 0
lastTime = time()
fps = None

def update():
    global p, x, curve, data, curve2, data2, ptr, lastTime, fps
    if ptr < len(x):
        curve.setData(x=x[:ptr], y=data[:ptr])
        curve2.setData(x=x[:ptr], y=data2[:ptr])
        ptr += 1
        now = time()
        dt = now - lastTime
        lastTime = now
        if fps is None:
            fps = 1.0/dt
        else:
            s = np.clip(dt*3., 0, 1)
            fps = fps * (1-s) + (1.0/dt) * s
        p.setTitle('%0.2f fps' % fps)
    else:
        ptr = 0
    app.processEvents()  ## force complete redraw for every plot.  Try commenting out to see if a different in speed occurs.
timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start(0)



## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: It will be also in great help for all if you put some remarks what you did/change/write etc.